# Testing Facebook Messenger Reply Flow

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am trying to integrate Facebook Messenger to my app. However, it seems like for the reply flow to work, app needs to be on App Store and approved by Facebook. I doubt the app would be approved by App Store without the reply flow working. Is there any way of breaking out of the cycle?

Comment: Why do the app needs the reply flow to be approved?

Comment: I guess not. It will have very limited functionality. I have submitted it for review. Hopefully it works.

Thanks btw!

It would be nice if Facebook Messenger did allow test users to see the reply/install button though. I am coding with Ionic/Cordova and integrating native code alongside which means there is a lot of chance of breakage. It would be good to test before asking Facebook and App Store for approval.. you know?

Comment: You can develop and test this with any account that has a role in your app (admins/developers/testers). Once that is done, you can submit for review following the instructions Facebook gives for this.